# CSS row broken after including php page in html

Tags: php, html, css

i have a problem with css row and columns, when i include php file in html my columns only arrange vertically

this is for my dashboard website, and i have try to find solution but no luck

when i put code like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="list">
    <div class="bg-mattBlackLight my-2 p-4">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" id="list">
    <div class="bg-mattBlackLight my-2 p-4">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" id="list">
    <div class="bg-mattBlackLight my-2 p-4">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Works perfectly with column size and placement 
(screen shot: https://ibb.co/tqRvBtL)
[image]

but when i include php page like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="list">
    <div class="bg-mattBlackLight my-2 p-4">
        <?php include 'php/user-list.php';?>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" id="list">
    <div class="bg-mattBlackLight my-2 p-4">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" id="list">
    <div class="bg-mattBlackLight my-2 p-4">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the columns arrange is vertical 
(screen shot: https://ibb.co/Q6qQJDJ)
[image]
Dose anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: Looks like hp/user-list.php generates some output what damages your layout.

Comment: make sure you have closed all the open tags inside php files

Comment: Of course we need to have the output or code of `user-list.php`, too

Comment: when i copy code from user-list.php into div, it work perfect, this only happening when i put include function.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar - Thanks man it was tags problem. You are the man. And of course thanks all of you for help. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure you have closed all the open tags inside PHP files

Comment: this was better left as a comment